# How to resolve this error when deploying on firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to deploy a function to Firebase, using the command:

`firebase deploy --only functions`

Here is the Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I copied the error from my `node.js` file,  Now I'm having this error:
 i  deploying functions

> Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
>       npm ERR! path C:\Users\Pc1\Desktop\TimeCard\TimeCardA\src\app\index\firecast\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
>       npm ERR! code ENOENT
>       npm ERR! errno -4058
>       npm ERR! syscall open
>       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Pc1\Desktop\TimeCard\TimeCardA\src\app\index\firecast\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
>       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       npm ERR! enoent
>       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pc1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-23T03_23_10_348Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238

```
C:\Users\Pc1\Desktop\TimeCard\TimeCardA\src\app\index\firecast>npm run deploy
npm ERR! missing script: deploy

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pc1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-23T03_33_19_115Z-debug.log
```

Comment: can you share the piece of code which is getting an error  and log "2018-07-23T03_23_10_348Z-debug.log"

Comment: there seems to be no `package.json` present ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with deploy function to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315948/error-with-deploy-function-to-firebase)

Comment: index.js  :     exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
                    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
                        });

Comment: I did exactly the firebase documentation requested ... and the error remains

Comment: at the time of making the firebase deploy --only functions, it gives the above errors